# Open "file" from memory stream?

Tags: c#, file, memorystream

I am wondering if its even possible. I am returning files from database (blob) and have them as bytes array. I would like to let the user to show the data content by clicking on associated object - something like opening in the WebBrowser which automatically selects the appropriate program..but I understand I would need to save the file to the disk.
Is there any other solution which would work only from streams/byte arrays?

Comment: What is the host application? ASP.NET, WinForms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try setting the [WebBrowser.DocumentStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentstream.aspx) property:

```
browser.DocumentStream = new MemoryStream(blob);
```